# Google's Web & App Activity suddenly not working

Tags: samsung, google-account

Up until yesterday, all my activity carried out on my Samsung Galaxy S20 showed up in my Web & App Activity in my Google account. However today, it stopped. Only showed when I used one app in particular and nothing else. I didn’t change any of my device or Google settings.

Anyone know why this would have happened and how to fix this?